# How to navigate Asp.net GridView with arrow keys as like in winform datagridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a '.aspx' Web Form with Gridview,
and if I press the UP/Down arrow key focus should be on Gridview and the Highlight should move to the next row.
Is there any solution for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is possible without any third party control. What you need to do is to apply sound logic for this. Check below link for your solution where answer has been posted and marked it as an answer.

[gridview to allow keyboard commands](http://forums.asp.net/t/1200983.aspx?How%20do%20I%20set%20the%20gridview%20to%20allow%20keyboard%20commands%20such%20as%20delete%20up%20down%20etc)

Comment: your answer is correct..!! But I got an even better link which causes no postback..!! this is the link [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25675/GridView-Rows-Navigation-Using-Arrow-Up-Down-Keys)

Comment: sure..!! but i need to get more reputation to do that..!!